# MySQL order a table by groups

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with the fields *id*, *group*, *left*, *level* and *createdAt*.

Every row belongs to a *group*. The row with *level* = 0 is the group "leader".

I want to sort the table by the leaders' date, and within each group sort the rows by *left*. For example, in this table:

```
Id - Group - Left - Level - CreatedAt
1    1       1      0       00:10
2    1       2      1       00:20
3    2       1      0       00:00
4    1       3      1       00:30
5    2       2      1       00:40
```

The order should be:

```
Id - Group - Left - Level - CreatedAt
3    2       1      0       00:00
5    2       2      1       00:40
1    1       1      0       00:10
2    1       2      1       00:20
4    1       3      1       00:30
```

Because row 3 is the newest group leader, it should be first and followed by all it's group ordered by *left*. After that is row 1 which is the second most new leader, followed by it's group ordered by *left*.
Etc..

I hope I explained it clear enough.

Thanks!

Comment: You generally should avoid using group for a column name, as it is a mysql reserved word, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Yea, you right, I don't really have that column name, it was just to make the question simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need to join your table with the leader's time:

```
SELECT my_table.*
FROM   my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   my_table.Group, MIN(my_table.CreatedAt) AS LeaderTime
  FROM     my_table
  WHERE    my_table.Level = 0
  GROUP BY my_table.Group
) t
ORDER BY t.LeaderTime, my_table.Left
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ee9c/1/0).

If you can *guarantee* that there is an unambiguous leader for every group—e.g. because you have defined a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(Group, Level)`, which you cannot have because your example contains two records in `Group = 1` with `Level = 1`—then you can avoid the grouping operation:

```
SELECT   my_table.*
FROM     my_table JOIN my_table AS leader
      ON leader.Group = my_table.Group AND leader.Level = 0
ORDER BY leader.CreatedAt, my_table.Left
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort on the group leader's createdAt, you can join each row to the row describing the group leader, then do the sorting:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM my_table t1
INNER JOIN  my_table t2
ON t1.Group = t2.Group AND t2.Level = 0
ORDER BY t2.CreatedAt, t1.Left;
```

Comment: What happens if there is more than one group leader?

Comment: @eggyal The the answer is unspecified (as the question implies that each group has _one_ leader), in this case returning duplicate rows.

Comment: Indeed--it's worth clarifying, especially since the example demonstrates that `(Group, Level)` is not unique.